# Mixed Gigabit And Non-Gigabit Devices

Tags: networking, file-transfer, dhcp, gigabit-ethernet, data-transfer

Suppose Say I have a Wifi Router which Has DHCP enabled in its LAN ports. Its LAN max Speed Is 450Mbps

I have an Unmanaged Switch Which Has 5 Gigabit Ethernet Port.

And I have a Desktop and a NAS both Have Gigabit LAN controller. They Both are connected to Gigabit Switch.

Now If I connect My devices like this, what will be the `maximum transfer rate between my Desktop And My NAS?` Is it will be Gigabit or 450Mbps?

```
Wifi Router(DHCP Server)(Non GbE)
       |
       |
Unmanaged Switch(GbE)
       |
   -------------------
   |                 |
Desktop(GbE)     NAS(GbE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on your network configuration. If they are on separate networks you will require the router for routing. If they are on the same network you'd get a gigabit connection as they could "directly" establish connection.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As I mentioned its A unmanaged switch, so all the devices are in same network. It's just a Hub Actually.

Comment: @mithucste30: I think "separate networks" here means IP subnets – it's technically possible that someone would have multiple subnets on the same unmanaged switch. Traffic between subnets goes through the router; traffic within same subnet is direct. (Note that Gigabit Ethernet mandates point-to-point connections and there's no way a hub could provide those. And if it did, it wouldn't _be_ a hub anymore, it'd be a switch.)

Comment: @grawity I am not sure actually, its this device https://www.tendacn.com/en/product/sg105.html

Comment: that is by definition, a switch.